# How can I load startup programs without logging in during system start

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

Many of my startup programs do not load until I log on to my account, when the computer starts.

If I set up auto login, the system is ready - and anyone who switches the comp on gets access to my account. I don't want that.

How can I setup my PC to wait for my password, while having loaded all my startup programs in the background?

Comment: I use Windows 8, but I guess the answer will be pertinent for other versions as well.

Comment: The simplest solution.  Automatically log into the account then set it to lock after a few minutes.  You can also log into the account then lock the account yourself.  Otherwise there isn't a way to do what you want ( load the start-up programs in the background )

Comment: Can you give examples of the type of thing you would want to run at boot?

Comment: Examples: f.lux, speedfan, Firefox